# Is there any way for converting Jetpack Compose Typeface to native Typeface?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-typeface

I'm trying to draw text using `NativeCanvas` and `NativePaint`. I want to use Jetpack `compose` `FontFamily` and `Typeface` but I have to use native `Typeface`.

I couldn't get font path from `compose` `FontFamily` to create a native `Typeface`.

**Is there any way for converting `Compose` `Typeface` to native `Typeface`?**

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is a way to covert compose typeface to native.
Currently the only workaround that i found is to provide with resources:

```
val textTypeface: android.graphics.Typeface? =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) LocalContext.current.resources.getFont(R.font.quicksand_light) else null
```

However if android version < android oreo, idk how to provide the font, so i fallback to default fount.

Comment: You can use [ResourcesCompat.getFont()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/res/ResourcesCompat#getFont(android.content.Context,int)) to get the font on older Android versions